# How to uninstall OpenERP-7 module in ubuntu 12.04 ?

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-12.04, odoo

I am using OpenERP 7 with Ubuntu 12.04. I have been trying to install Aero Reports module for creating OpenERP reports. I faced some "XML issues " during installation.

Now when I try to remove the module it says "Integrity Error

The operation cannot be completed, probably due to the following:
- deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it" .Plz help me to fix this issue

Hopes for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

uninstallation of module will surely bring up some surprises with openerp, so better to test the module for functionality and features in a test system and when you are sure about things install it in LIVE system.

For your problem, just check if there is any aeroo report is in the system, if yes delete the report and it's actions manually.

Comment: look I had manually deleted the Aero Reports from the system , but I am unable to delete it from the OpenERP . Now what should I do